# MySQL: Compare BETWEEN time

Tags: mysql

This may be impossible in the way that I'd like to have it work, but here goes.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE CAST('05:00:00' AS time) BETWEEN `start` AND `end`
```

The entries in the database are:

```
`start` = '22:59:59'
`end` = '06:00:00'
```

However, the query returns no results. Of course, this would work if there were dates involved, however there are not. It would also work if the start was = '00:00:00'.

Comment: So time of day is all that matters, not date?  Split it into two parts ( ... between '00:00:00' and '06:00:00' ) or ( between '22:59:59' and '23:59:59' ) perhaps?

Comment: ... Or invert the logic and make it NOT BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '22:59:59'?

Comment: Didn't think of that, definitely one way to do it, the logic just doesn't make sense in the context of the application. Thanks for the suggestion though, may be the only option.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

i think what you are looking for is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE start < CAST('05:00:00' AS time) AND end > CAST('05:00:00' AS time)
```

I'm not sure if you need to use the [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)s, though this should also work.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE start < '05:00:00' AND end > '05:00:00'
```

Comment: An important point to remember here is that if your times are formatted in 24 hour format you need to match it in the query, so the above might be more than likely "SELECT * FROM table WHERE start < CAST('05:00:00' AS time) AND end > CAST('17:00:00' AS time)'"

Answer (score 19):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    `table`
WHERE   CAST('05:00:00' AS time) BETWEEN `start` AND `end`
        OR (NOT CAST('05:00:00' AS time) BETWEEN `end` AND `start` AND `start` > `end`)
```

Comment: you are genious! it must be marker as answer instead of the current one!

Comment: You just saved me *_*

Answer (score 4):

I just came across this question and I had the same problem.  My solution is as follow:

```
SET @time = '05:00:00';

SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE IF(
        `start` < `end`,
        CAST(@time AS TIME) BETWEEN `start` AND `end`,
        (CAST(@time AS TIME) BETWEEN CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME) AND `end`) OR 
        (CAST(@time AS TIME) BETWEEN `start` AND CAST('24:00:00' AS TIME))
    ) = 1;
```

Hope it helps someone in the future.

Thank you Martin for the hint!

Answer (score 4):

We can compare time using simple *time to seconds* function. Use the following:

```
SELECT id
FROM table1
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC('2014-03-05 04:17:47') >= TIME_TO_SEC('2014-03-05 04:17:47');
```