# comparison operators between time values mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime-comparison

I am trying to return all the records on a certain date and less than an exact time
my SQL looks like this

- WHERE date = '2014-08-28'
- and  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) < '14:48:22'
  This returns all the time records and doesn't cutoff the time at the specified point
- WHERE date = '2014-08-28'
- and time < '14:48:22'
  This query cuts off the time at '14:28:22' but also cuts off all time before '10:00:00'

I have also tried the cast() but no luck

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
WHERE date = '2014-08-28' and time < time('14:48:22')
```

It looks like the comparison without `time()` is somehow being done with numbers rather than times.

Comment: I got the error <br/> Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '<'

Comment: I fount the answer here  <br/>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714899/mysql-compare-between-time?rq=1

Comment: Using the Time_to_Sec example

Comment: I imagine the illegal mix of collations is on the `date` part, so you could try `date = date('2014-08-28')`.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(0) FROM oc_marchenthoursofoperations 
WHERE dayes = DAYNAME(NOW()) AND TIME(CURRENT_TIME()) BETWEEN TIME( CONVERT(`fromtime`,TIME)) 
AND TIME(CONVERT(`totime`,TIME))  AND `marchentid`='MTN-MAR-00052';
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation for your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.  When the question is vague, this is even more important than usual!