# How to stop user from sending request for the same time slot?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this page in php where the user can click on the time slot and book a room. Now the issue I have found is Suppose an user1 books room from 4 to 6. Then another user2 comes & request the room from 3.30 to 5. It takes the request which should not be allowed. The request is sent to admin and saved in the database i.e MySQL.

The worry is if the admin rejects the request of user1 then user2 should be allowed. But if admin accepts user1 request then user2 should be given an error message or something to stop the booking of same time slot. Really confused how to stop this.

```
<?php session_start(); if(isset($_GET[ 'selecteddate'])) { $selecteddate=$_GET[ 'selecteddate']; } else { $selecteddate=date( "Y-m-d"); } ?>
<html>

<head>
    <title>MRA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
        #heading {
            text-align: right;
            font-size: 25px;
            float: right;
            margin: 50px 20px;
        }

        a:hover {
            color: #BEBEBC;
        }

        a {
            color: black;
        }

        #img {
            margin: 10px 10px;
        }

        #td {
            border-radius: 15px;
            border-style: dotted solid;
        }

        .name-error,
        .meeting-error {
            color: red;
            margin: 0 10px;
        }

        #plan {
            position: fixed;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -239px;
            top: 50%;
            margin-top: -150px;
            z-index: 10;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        #plan-bg {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            background: #000;
            opacity: 0.8;
            top: 0;
            display: none;
            z-index: 5;
        }

        .close {
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            right: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .close:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        #datepicker {
            width: 40%;
            float: left;
        }

        .calender-date {
            padding: 0 10px;
        }

        #time-slot-msg,
        #alert-msg {
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            background: #fff;
            font-size: 25px;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            margin: -50px 0 0 -184.5px;
            display: none;
            z-index: 10;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        #time-slot-msg p,
        #alert-msg p {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        #time-slot-msg .close,
        #alert-msg .close {
            font-size: 15px;
            right: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var $index;
            var systemdate = new Date();
            $('.meeting-error').hide();
            $(".meeting-timetable tr > td + td").click(function(e) {
                if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert('The selected time slot has already been assigned');
                } else {
                    var $thisVal = $(this).prevAll('td:first-child').text();
                    var hour = $thisVal.substr(0, 2);
                    var min = $thisVal.substr(3, 3);
                    var d = new Date("<?php print $selecteddate; ?>");
                    var n = d.getFullYear();
                    var m = d.getDate();
                    var k = d.getMonth();
                    var userdate = new Date(n, k, m, hour, min, 0);
                    if (systemdate > userdate) {
                        alert("Select Time Slot greater than the Current Time");
                        return;
                    }
                    $index = $(this).index();
                    // Start time.
                    $(".start-time option").each(function() {
                        if (($(this).text() === $thisVal)) {
                            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                            $(this).prevAll().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        }
                    });
                    // Change end time.
                    $(".end-time option").each(function() {
                        if (($(this).text() === $thisVal)) {
                            $(this).next().attr('selected', 'selected');
                            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                            $(this).prevAll().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        }
                    });
                    // Date input select.
                    var $date = $('.meeting-timetable tr:first-child th').text();
                    var dateFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date($date));
                    $('.date').val(dateFormat);
                    $('#meeting').val('');
                    $('.meeting-error').hide();
                    // Show dialog box.
                    var _cellIndex = $(this)[0].cellIndex;
                    var _rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr')[0].sectionRowIndex;
                    var total_row = $('.meeting-timetable tr').length - 1;
                    if (_rowIndex == total_row && _cellIndex == 1) {
                        alert('You cannot select this time slot');
                    } else $('#plan, #plan-bg').fadeIn();
                }
            });
            // On submit click change background color.
            $('.submit-button').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var selectedValue = $(".start-time option:selected").text(),
                    selectedEndValue = $(".end-time option:selected").text(),
                    $name = $('input[name=txtname]').val();
                if ($('#meeting').val()) {
                    $(".meeting-timetable tr > td").each(function() {
                        if ($(this).text() === selectedValue) {
                            $(this).parent('tr').addClass('active');
                        }
                        if ($(this).text() === selectedEndValue) {
                            var $parent = $(this).parent('tr').prevUntil('tr.active').addClass('active');
                        }
                        // Prev all td selected.
                        $($parent).each(function() {});
                    });
                }
                // Form validation.
                if ($('#meeting').val() === '') {
                    $('.meeting-error').fadeIn();
                }
                // Grab form values
                var formData = {
                    'txtrname': $('input[name=txtrname]').val(),
                    'txtname': $('input[name=txtname]').val(),
                    'txtpurpose': $('input[name=txtpurpose]').val(),
                    'attendee': $('select[name=attendee]').val(),
                    'txtdate': $('input[name=txtdate]').val(),
                    'btime': $('select[name=btime]').val(),
                    'etime': $('select[name=etime]').val()
                };
                if ($('#meeting').val().trim()) {
                    // Ajax form submit.
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "insertkarma.php",
                        data: formData,
                        success: function() {
                            $('#alert-msg').fadeIn();
                            $('#plan').fadeOut();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    alert('Please enter the purpose of meeting');
                }
            });
            // on focus function
            $('#meeting').focus(function() {
                $('.meeting-error').fadeOut();
            }).blur(function() {
                if (!$(this).val()) {
                    $('.meeting-error').fadeIn();
                }
            });
            $(".close").click(function() {
                $('.pop-up').fadeOut();
            });
            // Adding calender.
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                minDate: 0,
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                onSelect: function(date) {
                    var url = "karma.php?selecteddate=" + date;
                    window.location.assign(url);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body background="a6.jpg">
    <a href="homepage.php"><img id="img" src="HITECHLOGO.jpg" width="150px" height="100px"></a>
    <h1 align="center" style="position:absolute;top:30px; left:600px;">KARMA<br> (3-SEATER)</h1>
    <div id="heading"><a href="homepage.php" style="text-decoration:none;">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?php echo ucwords($_SESSION[ 'usr_name']); ?>
        </font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="logout.php" style="text-decoration:none;">Logout</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="UserManual.pdf" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">Help</a>
    </div>
    <hr width="100%">
    <?php $host="localhost" ;  $username="root" ;  $password="" ; $db_name="testing" ;  $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die( "cannot connect"); mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name); $i=0 ; $dateEntry="SELECT `starttime` , `status_id` , `name` , floor(( time_to_sec(`endtime`)-time_to_sec(`starttime`) )/1800) as testing FROM `details` WHERE `date` = '$selecteddate' order by starttime" ; if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$dateEntry)) { while ($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($result)) { $starttime[$i]=$ obj->starttime; $status[$i] = $obj->status_id; $name[$i] = $obj->name; $testing[$i] = $obj->testing; $i++; } } mysqli_close($conn); ?>
    <table border="1" align="right" width="60%" style="border:black;">
        <tr>
            <td id="td" colspan="3" align="center">
                <h1>Click to Book a Time Slot</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="red" align="center" id="td">Booked</td>
            <td id="td" align="center" bgcolor="orange">Requested</td>
            <td align="center" id="td">Available</td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="td" colspan="3">| <a href="karma.php"> Today </a> |</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="meeting-timetable" border="1" align="right" width="60%" style="border:black;">
        <tr>
            <th id="td" colspan="2" class="calender-date" align="center">
                <?php print $selecteddate; ?>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="08:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; " width="10%">08:00</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="08:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">08:30</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="09:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">09:00</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="09:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">09:30</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="10:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">10:00</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="10:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">10:30</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="11:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">11:00</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="11:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">11:30</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="12:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">12:00</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="12:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">12:30</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="13:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">13:00</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="13:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">13:30</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="14:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">14:00</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="14:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">14:30</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="15:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">15:00</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="15:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">15:30</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="16:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">16:00</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="16:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">16:30</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="17:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">17:00</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="17:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">17:30</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="18:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">18:00</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="18:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">18:30</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="19:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">19:00</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="19:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">19:30</td>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="20:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 15px;border-style: dotted solid; ">20:00</td>
            <td id="td" class="showAlert"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="plan" class="pop-up" style="display :none ">
        <span class="close">Close</span>
        <form align="center" method="post" id="inform">
            <h1 align="center">Meeting Details</h1>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Room : </td><td><input type="text" name="txtrname" value="Karma" readonly></td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>Name :</td><td><input type="text" name="txtname" readonly value="<?php echo ucwords($_SESSION['usr_name']);  ?>"   ></td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>Purpose of Meeting :</td><td> <input id="meeting" type="text" name="txtpurpose"><span class="meeting-error">Enter the purpose of meeting</span></td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>No. of Attendee :</td><td><select name="attendee"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select></td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>Date :</td><td> <input class="date" type="text" name="txtdate" readonly value="yyyy/mm/dd"></td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>Time : </td><td>Start Time <select class="start-time" name="btime">
     <option value="08:00:00">08:00</option>
     <option value="08:30:00">08:30</option>
     <option value="09:00:00">09:00</option>
     <option value="09:30:00">09:30</option>
     <option value="10:00:00">10:00</option>
     <option value="10:30:00">10:30</option>
     <option value="11:00:00">11:00</option>
     <option value="11:30:00">11:30</option>
     <option value="12:00:00">12:00</option>
     <option value="12:30:00">12:30</option>
     <option value="13:00:00">13:00</option>
     <option value="13:30:00">13:30</option>
     <option value="14:00:00">14:00</option>
     <option value="14:30:00">14:30</option>
     <option value="15:00:00">15:00</option>
     <option value="15:30:00">15:30</option>
     <option value="16:00:00">16:00</option>
     <option value="16:30:00">16:30</option>
     <option value="17:00:00">17:00</option>
     <option value="17:30:00">17:30</option>
     <option value="18:00:00">18:00</option>
     <option value="18:30:00">18:30</option>
     <option value="19:00:00">19:00</option>
     <option value="19:30:00">19:30</option>
     <option value="20:00:00" disabled>20:00</option>
     </select>
     - End Time <select class="end-time" name="etime">
     <option value="08:00:00">08:00</option>
     <option value="08:30:00">08:30</option>
     <option value="09:00:00">09:00</option>      
     <option value="09:30:00">09:30</option>
     <option value="10:00:00">10:00</option>
     <option value="10:30:00">10:30</option>
     <option value="11:00:00">11:00</option>
     <option value="11:30:00">11:30</option>
     <option value="12:00:00">12:00</option>
     <option value="12:30:00">12:30</option>
     <option value="13:00:00">13:00</option>
     <option value="13:30:00">13:30</option>
     <option value="14:00:00">14:00</option>
     <option value="14:30:00">14:30</option>
     <option value="15:00:00">15:00</option>
     <option value="15:30:00">15:30</option>
     <option value="16:00:00">16:00</option>
     <option value="16:30:00">16:30</option>
     <option value="17:00:00">17:00</option>
     <option value="17:30:00">17:30</option>
     <option value="18:00:00">18:00</option>
     <option value="18:30:00">18:30</option>
     <option value="19:00:00">19:00</option>
     <option value="19:30:00">19:30</option>
     <option value="20:00:00">20:00</option>
     </select>
     </td></tr>
     <tr></tr>
     <tr><td></td><td><input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit"    </td></tr></table></form></div>
     <div id="plan-bg" class="pop-up"></div>
     <div id="alert-msg" class="pop-up"><span class="close" onclick="window.location.reload();">Close</span><p>Your request has been sent to admin.</p></div>
     <div id="time-slot-msg" class="pop-up"><span class="close">Close</span><p>This time slot is already booked.</p></div>
     <div id="datepicker"></div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     var jqueryarray = [];
     jqueryarray = <?php echo json_encode($starttime); ?>;
     var statusarray=[];
     statusarray = <?php echo json_encode($status); ?>;
     var namearray=[];
     namearray = <?php echo json_encode($name); ?>;
     var countarray = [];
     countarray = <?php echo json_encode($testing); ?>;
     var arr = [];
     for(i = 0; i < <?php echo $i; ?>; i++)
     {
        arr[i] = jqueryarray[i];
     }
     var brr = [];
     for(i = 0; i < <?php echo $i; ?>; i++)
     {
       brr[i] = statusarray[i];
     }
     var crr=[];
     for(i=0; i< <?php echo $i; ?>; i++)
     {
      crr[i] = namearray[i];
     } 
     var drr=[];
     for(i=0; i< <?php echo $i; ?>; i++)
     {
      drr[i] = countarray[i];
     } 
     var j = 0;
     var k=1;
     var currentrow;
     $('.meeting-timetable tr').each(function() {
      if(arr[j] == $(this).find('td').attr('id')) 
      {
       if(brr[j]==1)
       {
         currentrow=$(this);
         for(k=1;k<=parseInt(countarray[j]);k++)
         {
           currentrow.find('td').next().css('background-color','orange').addClass('active').attr("title",namearray[j]);
           currentrow=currentrow.next('tr');
         }
       }
       if(brr[j]==2)
       {
         currentrow=$(this);
         for(k=1;k<=parseInt(countarray[j]);k++)
         {
           currentrow.find('td').next().css('background-color','red').addClass('active').attr("title",namearray[j]);
           currentrow=currentrow.next('tr');
         }
       }
       if(brr[j]==3)
       {
         $(this).find('td').next().css('background-color', '');
       }
       if(brr[j]==4)
       {
         $(this).find('td').next().css('background-color', '');
       }
       j++;  
       }
       });
       </script>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: I think we need another 5 pages of code to dig through.

Comment: @Devon this is the complete page.Using this user can book a time slot for a room.Now the issue is if someone else uses should not be allowed to overwrite the already requested time slot.Maybe we can use sql query to check if other user has already requested or booked the room for time slot.

Comment: Ankit, @Devon was pointing out that your code sample could do with trimming down to a simpler case that still exhibits the problem at hand. Presently you have dumped the whole file and asked us to debug it, which is not really how this site works.

Comment: I expect [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933400/check-for-time-overlap-in-mysql) is basically a re-ask of this one.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this like so:

If we do not want or cannot use complete timestamp with date and time,

- convert HH:MM:SS format to seconds (link: [Convert time in HH:MM:SS format to seconds only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834202/convert-hhmmss-to-seconds-only))
- setup db table for bookings, somnething like - id, user_id, start, end, approved_satus
- write those values to this table
- you could use a basic numeric comparison operations to check whether certain value is in range, since we store start and end times in seconds

Something for you to work with, not inclined to write complete code here.

Comment: I have table in db which stores the user_id start time end time & status..Status is also a table which is has status_id column which works as a foreign key in this table.

Comment: The key in my suggestion is to use numeric values for start and end times, so to simplify comparison process.

Comment: Then you could try comparing times based on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714899/mysql-compare-between-time

Comment: MySQL INSERT Syntax does not support the WHERE clause, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query

Comment: It would probably be more user friendly if, instead of letting the user to submit the form with taken slot, you prevent him from selecting these slots in the first place by implementing some AJAX lookup.

Comment: I have done as you said. Now the issue is if user1 book time slot 3 to 5 & user 2 request for time slot 2.30 to 6 then this should not be allowed.If user2 selects time slot 3 he will get alert message. The issue is of overlapping of time slots between 2 users

Comment: Please see this for dealing with time ranges in mySQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571538/checking-a-table-for-time-overlap