# Check for time overlap in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a page where the user books the room.The details of booking is sent to another page where i have insert query.I tried the code for checking the overlapping & printing the alert message on the main booking page but the query isn't working.Please help!

```
$room = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtrname']);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtname']);
$purpose = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtpurpose']);
$attendee = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['attendee']);
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtdate']);
$btime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['btime']);
$etime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['etime']);

$a="SELECT * from roomdetails WHERE (date=$date AND (endtime > '" . $btime . "') AND (starttime < '" . $etime . "'))";
if($a == true)
{
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Please select another time slot")';  
    echo '</script>';
}
else
{
   $sql="INSERT INTO roomdetails(room,name,purpose,attendee,date,starttime,endtime,status_id)VALUES('$room','$name','$purpose','$attendee','$date','$btime','$etime','1')";
}
if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
{
   echo "Record added";
}
else
{
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
}
```

Comment: look at syntax highlighting in your posted code; there's a syntax error in your query. always define "doesn't work" too. You're also not doing anything with `$a`.

Comment: Please indent your code, for the love of everything that is holy!

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: As Fred -ii- pointed out, you are not firing the $a query. Secondly, the condition ($a == true)

Answer (score 1):

The condition `$a==true` will always be true since "$a" is a string and not empty.

I would suggest you to fire the query and then check the result and you might succeed.