# Select rows that fall between two times

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field that is a a DATETIME field.

How do I select rows that fall between between 12:00 am and 8:30 am?

when I type in this query:

```
 $query = "select * from table where TIME(changetime) between '12:00:00 and '08:30:00'";
```

it gives me zero hits.

The changetime field has the date like this: 2015-07-14 10:57:57

Comment: 08:30:00 is before 12:00:00 - also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714899/mysql-compare-between-time

Answer (score 3):

`12:00:00` is 12 PM (noon), not 12 AM (midnight). You need to use

```
WHERE TIME(changetime) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '08:30:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

1) you don't need TIME(changetime), it could probably worsen your search-time because mysql will need to apply a function instead of using index.

use just changetime.

2) `where changetime between '2015-07-14 10:57:57' and '2015-07-14 12:57:57'` 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

3) you need to use right range - in your example END_DATE is BEFORE START_DATE. So, between will return 0 (12:00:00 > 08:30:00)

4) look at @Barmar's comment, maybe you really want entries between some time in any date, not between the datetimes

Comment: If he does it like that, it will only find rows on a specific date, not all days between those times.