# Search between two dates with specific time with each date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two dates. `2019-01-01(fromDate)` and `2019-01-10(toDate)`. And now I want to search only the `13:00` to `16:00` time of each date. May I ask if is it possible using query only? Any answer is much appreciated

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE fromDate >= 2019-01-01 AND toDate <= 2019-01-10
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714899/mysql-compare-between-time Look at this to know more on comparing time

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What are you actually comparing?

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function with the format and `HOUR` function.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE 
    fromDate >= STR_TO_DATE('2019-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d') 
AND 
    toDate <= STR_TO_DATE('2019-01-10', '%Y-%m-%d')
AND
    (HOUR(fromDate) BETWEEN 13 AND 16 OR HOUR(toDate) BETWEEN 13 AND 16)
```

Comment: The query does not filter the records between those hours.

Comment: based on your example  this `2019-01-01 13:00:00` is fromDate. And toDate is `2019-01-01 16:00:00`. What about the next date `2019-01-02`. I want to also search the time which is from `13:00:00` to `16:00:00` in all dates. Is that possible?

Comment: Thank you for your knowledge. Regarding the added query `(HOUR(fromDate) BETWEEN 13 AND 16 OR HOUR(toDate) BETWEEN 13 AND 16)`. Is it possible to add minute on it. For example `13:55:00`.

Comment: Yes you can try to use `MINUTE` function. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_minute

Comment: Okay I see. Let me try this. Thank you for sharing knowledge. I'll accept the answer later. I will just try it first.

Answer (score 3):

Use separate conditions on the date and on the time:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE fromDate >= '2019-01-01' AND
      toDate < '2019-01-11' and
      time(fromdate) between '13:00:00' and '16:00:00' and
      time(todate) between '13:00:00' and '16:00:00;
```

Or, if you don't want `16:00:00` exactly, you can use `hour()`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE fromDate >= '2019-01-01' AND
      toDate < '2019-01-11' and
      hour(fromdate) in (13, 14, 15) and
      hour(todate) in (13, 14, 15)
```