# Mysql-cast and convert in joins is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

In a MySQL table, they have stored `return_time` as VARCHAR(20) and `return_date` as a date field. Now I have to compare this based on the given date and time and produce the result. For example, records save in the time column will be like '10:00 PM', '11:00 PM', '02:00 AM' etc and in the date column like '2021-02-02', '2021-01-02' etc

I combined the `return_date`and `return_time`, and compare it with the given date and time like

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM `travel_infos` as TravelInfo 
 WHERE TravelInfo.travel_status = 'Open' AND  
      cast(concat(TravelInfo.return_date, ' ',  STR_TO_DATE(TravelInfo.return_time, '%l:%i %p' )) as datetime) > '2021-03-03 14:03'
```

It outputs me 231 records. `travel_infos` table has 700 records.

Then I do the join without considering the `return_time` column

```
SELECT Part.*,TravelInfo.*,Category.*,Buttons.* 
FROM travel_infos As TravelInfo 
LEFT JOIN  parts as Part ON Part.id = TravelInfo.part_id_1 
LEFT JOIN buttons as Buttons ON Part.button_name_id= Buttons.id 
LEFT JOIN categories as Category ON Part.category_id = Category.id 
WHERE Part.id != 0 AND TravelInfo.id!=0 
      AND Part.part_type IN('Charter') AND Part.store_id='1' 
      AND TravelInfo.travel_status = 'Open' 
      AND TravelInfo.return_date >= '2021-03-03 14:03' 
      AND Part.is_delete=0
```

It outputs me 175 records.

So now I want to join by considering both `return_date` and `return_time`. So I tried like

```
    SELECT Part.*,TravelInfo.*,Category.*,Buttons.* 
    FROM travel_infos As TravelInfo 
    LEFT JOIN parts as Part ON Part.id = TravelInfo.part_id_1 
    LEFT JOIN buttons as Buttons ON Part.button_name_id= Buttons.id 
    LEFT JOIN categories as Category ON Part.category_id = Category.id 
    WHERE Part.id != 0 AND
          TravelInfo.id!=0 
          AND Part.part_type IN('Charter') 
          AND Part.store_id='1' 
          AND TravelInfo.travel_status = 'Open' 
          AND (cast(concat(TravelInfo.return_date, ' ', 
              STR_TO_DATE(TravelInfo.return_time, '%l:%i %p' )) as datetime)) >= '2021-03-03 14:03' AND Part.is_delete=0
```

This outputs me 0 records. What went wrong in the 3rd SQL query? Both 1st and 2nd produce the output.
In my 3rd query, I modified the 2nd query `WHERE` like in the 1st query.

Can someone help me to solve this thank you.

Comment: Last line of 3rd query is ``TravelInfo.return`` or ``TravelInfo.return_date``?

Comment: I edited its return_date only.

Comment: Please change ``>=`` to ``>`` in last line and test result

Comment: Do not use string functions for datetime operations... `WHERE .. AND TIMESTAMP(return_date, STR_TO_DATE(return_time, '%h:%i %p')) >= '2021-03-03 14:03'`

Comment: Akina it is not working

Comment: Saeed Easmaeelinejad changing >= to > also returns empty results

Answer (score 0):

Convert both dates you are comparing to datetimes in the where clause:

```
SELECT Part.*,TravelInfo.*,Category.*,Buttons.* 
FROM travel_infos As TravelInfo 
LEFT JOIN parts as Part ON Part.id = TravelInfo.part_id_1 
LEFT JOIN buttons as Buttons ON Part.button_name_id= Buttons.id 
LEFT JOIN categories as Category ON Part.category_id = Category.id 
WHERE Part.id != 0 AND
  TravelInfo.id!=0 
  AND Part.part_type IN('Charter') 
  AND Part.store_id='1' 
  AND TravelInfo.travel_status = 'Open' 
  AND TravelInfo.return_date >= STR_TO_DATE('2021-03-03', '%Y-%m-%d')
  AND cast(TravelInfo.return_time as time) >= cast('14:03:00' as time) 
  AND Part.is_delete=0
```

Comment: Have you tried comparing the date component and the time component separately? Instead of concatenating them put each field in its own "AND" line, for comparing times look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714899/mysql-compare-between-time/4794540
I have updated my answer with the same; it should also perform better.
Finally, if you want to debug the query, remove the dates from the where clause and return them in the select so that you can verify that you actually have dates in all tables matching the where clause and joins